# Cannot get the extra from Fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to put an extra to a fragment in android. I have a list fragment, and when an item is clicked on the list, i want to pass its id as an extra to the next activity. Here is the code:

```
public class EmailListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        Email mail = ((CustomEmailFragmentAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),EmailFragmentActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(EmailFragment.EXTRA_EMAIL_ID, mail.getId());
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

and the **abstract** SingleFragmentActivity class:

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.email_fragment_container);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.email_fragment_container);
        if(fragment == null){
            fragment = createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.email_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

and the EmailFragmentActivity class:

```
public class EmailFragmentActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        UUID emailId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(
            EmailFragment.EXTRA_EMAIL_ID);

        return EmailFragment.newInstance(emailId);
    }

}
```

I pass mail.getId() as an extra and get the extra in EmailFragmentActivity class.
The problem is, the id i passed is different from the id i get in EmailFragmentActivity class. What am i doing wrong here? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you override getItem() in your CustomEmailFragmentAdapter?

Comment: I would expect mail.getId() to return an integer. Yet you cast the saved Extra to UUID. Could this be the problem?

Comment: So if it returns the right thing, what's the problem then? I'm confused.

Comment: UUID emailId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(
            EmailFragment.EXTRA_EMAIL_ID);  does not get the extra that i passed, it returns a different id